# What is the conceptual difference between convolutional neural networks and auto-encoders?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, comparison, autoencoders

I'm familiar with Auto-Encoders and I'm about to dive into CNNs. By having a look at the most important component of a CNN, the filter:

[image: img1]

I wonder how it is different from Auto-Encoders:

[image: img2]

For me, it looks conceptually the same. I even have to admit it is quite of another higher concept: Dimensionality reduction. In e.g. PCA, as well as in AE and in CNN(?) you transform higher data / higher dimensions onto lower / compressed data.
I can see that the methods are somehow different but yet, can't really explain in which manner, finally.

Comment: CNN is known to be good at extracting features from images, which is why auto encoders utilize CNN for the encoding part.

Comment: Ok, interesting..  so, in this context, CNN is half an AE.